# Git / Github - problem with commit visibility / history / git log -S

Tags: git, github, commit, git-log

I have a pretty weird problem with git. 
When I use the command: 
`git show {number of commit}` 
It shows me a commit that I made, and in this commit, I can clearly see that I used the "boolToString" function. With applies that the commit is existing. But when I use 
`git log -S boolToString {path to file}`
it does not find commit with this change. The path to file is correct because if I type some phrase that was there before my commit it is returning results. Does any of you come with a problem similar to mine? I would be more than thankful for any hints or ideas about what's going on.

Comment: Is that commit part of your currently checked out branch (or, more accurately, reachable in the history of your currently checked out commit)?

Comment: Yes, it is. I only work on one branch 'master'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What I think is most likely

I suspect History Simplification:

> ```
> git log -S boolToString {path to file}
> ```

Any time you run `git log [options] [--] path`, `git log` turns on History Simplification.  The goal of this simplification is to explain why your file looks the way it does *now.*  This means that if what you are trying to figure out is why a line you added, some time ago, has gone missing, you may get *no output*.  This happens when the line you added got *removed* during a `git merge` operation.

(I consider this a failure to meet the goal of explaining why the file is as it is now, but it is what it is.)

To find the merge in which the line was removed from the file, use:

```
git log -S boolToString --full-history -m -- path/to/file
```

The `--full-history` option turns off History Simplification, and the `-m` makes Git examine the merge commits so that you can see the line vanish.

#### Less likely, but possible

The `-S` option looks for commits that change the *number of occurrences* of some string.  That is:

```
git log -S boolToString
```

will show commits where `boolToString` is in a `+` line that is not balanced out by a corresponding `-` line, in the diff output, or vice versa.  If you're looking for a place where you made a change to one of the *arguments* to `boolToString`, for instance, you want `git log -G` rather than `git log -S`.

Answer (score 1):

You might try `git log --all -S boolToString {path to file}`.  If there are branches in your git tree, you will find them missing in regular `git log` output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work. I still can't see the commit responsible for the change. In "git log" I can see the commit responsible for that change tho.

Comment: Did that commit have a *change* associated with a *boolToString* line?  IE, does `git diff {commit}^..{commit}` show that that particular diff actually changed a line that had *boolToString* in it?